# How to delete SOLR indexed data by datetime field query with curl?

Tags: curl, solr, http-delete

I have a datetime field like that.

```
<field name="rel_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" default="NOW" multiValued="false"/>
```

I try to delete some specific dates on rel_date field by curl query.

```
curl http://$SOLR_IPADDR:$SOLR_PORT/solr/update/?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<delete><query>rel_date:\[2012-03-10\])</query></delete>"
```

But its getting Invalid date string error on SOLR response.

> **HTTP Status 400 - Invalid Date String:'[2012-03-10]'**

How can I delete specific dates on SOLR records with CURL query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the time as well.

From the [DateField javadocs](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/org/apache/solr/schema/DateField.html):

> A date field shall be of the form 1995-12-31T23:59:59Z The trailing
>   "Z" designates UTC time and is mandatory (See below for an explanation
>   of UTC). Optional fractional seconds are allowed, as long as they do
>   not end in a trailing 0 (but any precision beyond milliseconds will be
>   ignored). All other parts are mandatory.

See also: http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/lweug/Solr+Date+Format

Answer (score 0):

I did it with following curl comment:

> curl http://$SOLR_IPADDR:$SOLR_PORT/solr/update/?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "(rel_date:[2012-03-10T00:00:00Z TO 2012-03-10T00:00:00Z])"

Of cource you have to change $SOLR_IPADDR and $SOLR_PORT from your environment.

Answer (score 0):

curl http://host:port/solr/core_name/update?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" --data-binary `'<delete><query>rel_date:[2019-03-25T00:00:01Z TO 2019-03-25T23:59:59Z]</query></delete>'`